# Do I need Git installing on my remote sever?

Tags: git, server, installation

I'm just starting to get my head round Git because we are now growing as a team so now need versioning. I know I can have a repository on our server but do I need to install it too? Git site doesn't specify anything but I don't want assume anything either. Server is hybrid/vps (possibly moving soon to dedicated) running centos6. Thanks

Comment: You can install GitLab CE or Gogs as a repo server....

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman - unfortunately the main Gogs site doesn't work but will keep checking!

Comment: https://gogs.io/docs/installation/install_from_binary

Comment: Thanks again @Hackerman - but the page just returns a security error for me. I'll check back though.

Comment: That's weird...but anyway, about two years ago, we choose GitLab as our repo server and manager and it works great...a colleague of mine also proposed to switch to gogs because it uses much more less resources and it is really easy to deploy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should install Git on your server. Refer to the [Git installation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) chapter of the Git book.

Git is included in the standard CentOS repositories, so just doing `sudo yum install git` should work.

Comment: Thanks @DUman - it simply said 'install on your computer' which I took as my local one. I have options for adding to the remote one including git-all. Is that the best option or will just git do?

Comment: Git is a distributed system, it doesn't really do "server" and "local computers" the way some other systems do. If you're using one computer as a server, it's really just another computer that needs Git installed. `git-all` contains a bunch of packages for integrating with other versioning systems and such, you probably just need the base `git`. You can always add more later if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can setup GIT in a server role, but I suggest not going that way.  GIT in it's purest form has nothing much in the way of a permissions model.  You mention you are a growing team.

I would recommend Atlassian Bitbucket (either the cloud offering, or the locally hosted on-site Bitbucket Server).  For small teams it's very cost effective, and you get really nice things like Pull Request work-flows, permissions models, and other enterprise features.  It also hooks up really well to JIRA and Bamboo for defect tracking and build management, giving you a far better full life-cycle view of your code. You don't say how small your team is, but $10 for 10 users (charity donation) is a great starting point, and for functionality and scalability is blows other products like TFS out the water.  As it's GIT based, even if you want to switch down the road, you just import your repositories (even TFS can use GIT, and it even seems to be favoring GIT as the preferred backend)

https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/pricing?tab=host-on-your-server
https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/features

Other products worth considering:  GitHub Enterprise, GITLAB possibly others too.